# How to run WIX bootstrap built exe to run in silent mode?

Tags: wix, exe, uac, burn, wix3.8

Is it possible to run the exe built using WIX burn bootstrap to run in silent mode? I need to do this in order to skip the UAC prompt. Are there any better ways to skip the UAC prompt using the WIX project itself? Without making any changes to the registry keys manually.

Comment: You cannot skip the UAC prompt if you launch the exe from a user context. The UAC prompt is what elevates the process. If you want to run your bootstrapper with no UAC prompt you need to run as administrator or start it from an elevated cmd prompt/process. With UAC turned on you will always need to click yes on a UAC prompt somewhere to get an elevated process.

Answer (score 4):

Burn supports silent installations. Use the `/quiet` switch to run installation without any user interface. This will not show the UAC prompt.

```
AppInstaller.exe /install /quiet
```

If your installation requires elevated rights to install properly, run it from another already elevated process - either command line, or a management software.